# Setting contrasts in lme4: contr.treatment vs contr.sdif

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding, contrasts

1. In my study, each participant completed the very same Reaction Time task 3 times in 3 Sessions. I am not entirely sure if I should code the variable "Session" using `contr.treatment` or (a modified version of) `contr.sdif` [MASS].

For `contr.treatment(3)` (See below), I understand that the first contrast compares the second level against the first level while the second contrast compares the third level against the first level.

```
  2 3
1 0 0
2 1 0
3 0 1
```

In my study, this is exactly what I wanted: 2vs1 and 3vs1. However, I was told by someone that I should be using contr.sdif instead, assuming because the variable Session is a within-subject (or repeated) variable and that participants will improve across sessions.

However, in the default `contr.sdif` matrix, 2vs1 and 3vs2 are compared. I am not interested in 3vs2, so I manually created the following matrix so that 3vs2 is replaced by 3vs1.

```
#Modified contr.sdif(3) [Not sure if it is correct, if not please let me know]
            2-1        3-1
[1,]  0.3333333 -0.3333333
[2,] -0.6666667 -0.3333333
[3,]  0.3333333  0.6666667

#Default contr.sdif(3)
         2-1        3-2
[1,] -0.6666667 -0.3333333
[2,]  0.3333333 -0.3333333
[3,]  0.3333333  0.6666667
```

I am not entirely sure what the differences between the modified contr.sdif and the contr.treatment(3) are. Both are dealing with 2vs1 and 3vs1. I can't seem to find any reference that explains their difference. Is it true that contr.treatment is only for non-successive variable while contr.sdif is for successive categorical variables in which each level may in some way influence each other.

2. In the second contrast of the modified contrast.sdif, level 3 is compared against level 1, my understanding of why level 2 is not assigned with 0 is because this level has some influence on the 3vs1 comparison (since this is **successive** variable we are dealing with (e.g., participants improve across sessions).

In the first contrast of contr.sdif(3), level 2 is compared against level 1. However, level 3 has nothing to do with this 2vs1 comparison (i.e., my performance in session/level 3 will not influence my performance in session/levels 1 and 2 because session 3 takes place AFTER the two sessions. So I don't understand why isn't level 3 assigned with 0 since it has no influence on the 2vs 1 comparison?

3. Based on what I have read so far, non-orthogonal contrasts seem to be shunned in ANOVA or regression, so I am wondering if I should avoid using non-orthogonal contrasts like contr.sdif or contr.treatment in lme4.

Comment: um......how is my question not related to statistics or data analysis?

Comment: This *does* seem to be about statistics & data analysis to me, @matt, & not really about how to use R. But it's rather oblique & discussed in heavily R-based jargon--I suspect it isn't very understandable to others. Can you provide more context for this? Can you reframe it in a more software-neutral way? Could you post a small example dataset, or maybe some output, something concrete for people to sink their teeth into?